# Laravel : redirect to other url not previous on failed form validation

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-5

Note : I **DO NOT** want to redirect to previous url.

My registration form is a modal on the home page where i post my form to auth/register  but when validation error happen it redirect me back to home page. Where I want to redirect to another route  'auth/register' where validation error will be shown.

I went through AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers , ValidatesRequests , UrlGenerator. I found that it use header referer information to redirect me back to previous url.

Is there any way I can set in ***AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers*** traits  , ***postRegister*** method that if validation error happen from this method then redirect me to this specific url instead of using previous url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your own `postRegister()` method, and do your own validation and redirection in there. That is how it is designed - so you overload any method that you want to customise.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Not what i expected but solved my problem though.  I was expecting laravel to have some magic function to custom set the redirect url hehe

Comment: If you are using FormRequest validation - Laravel *does* have magic function to set the redirect url. But it doesnt in the trait for the Auth section.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by modifying AuthenticateAndRegisterUsers.php file located at:

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

I added this line:
            return redirect('auth/register')->withErrors($validator);

```
    public function postRegister(Request $request)
{

    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        /* $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        ); */
        return redirect('auth/register')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: It's not standard though, I guess you can overwrite postRegister function somewhere.

Comment: I highly suggest you don't do this. These files/codes will get replaced once you update laravel through composer update or install.  I did this kind of fixes and so I don't recommend it :)

Comment: Right, but still if you overwrite the postRegister method in AuthController, that'd do the trick without any problems, unless they change postRegister method in illuminate.